# Treat input argument in Scala function as a String in ScalikeJDBC select query

Tags: scala, jdbc

I have a function in Scala which returns a List[String]. I am using ScalikeJDBC.

```
def selectDQTableAndSiteList(schemaName:String) (implicit s:DBSession = AutoSession) : List[String] = {
   sql"select CONCAT(name, ${"#"} , age) as tablename from ${schemaName}.employee where status = 'Y'".map(_.string("tablename")).list().apply()
}
```

Let's say my input argument schemaName was abc. Then the select query is executed as 'abc'.employee and not abc.employee

What changes do I need to do so that it is treated as abc.employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQLSyntax.createUnsafely` to convert your string into `SQLSyntax`:

```
def selectDQTableAndSiteList(schemaName:String) (implicit s:DBSession = AutoSession) : List[String] = {
   val schema = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(schemaName)
   sql"select CONCAT(name, ${"#"} , age) as tablename from ${schema}.employee where status = 'Y'".map(_.string("tablename")).list().apply()
}
```